# Expanding a MySQL query versus analyzing it with PHP after fetching?

Tags: php, mysql

Please note, I'm a beginner. I have this table for a small webgame:

```
id AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
player1 INT (3),
player2 INT (3),
player3 INT (3),
player4 INT (3)
```

Assuming a row looks like this:

```
49, 1, 2, 0, 0
```

A player value that is not 0 indicates a player(id) is in that game. A zero shows an open slot.

Now, if I want to know how many free slots that game has, I currently do

```
SELECT * from games
```

and then use PHP foreach logic to count up the number of 0s, which in the case above would result in 2 open slots.

Would there be a quicker or more efficient way to do this without PHP, but by altering my * query in the first place? If so, how would it look?

Answer (score 1):

Just use the count?

E.g.

```
SELECT COUNT(id) FROM players WHERE [value] == 0
```

It is usually faster to place logic in the query than processing the data afterwards.

I didn't quite understand the structure so you will have to adjust the query a little I guess. If you don't have unique rows for each player in the table you will have to group them also.

Answer (score 0):

Use count as its faster - avoid using wildcards in your query.

```
SELECT
count(1)
FROM
games
WHERE
played_id = 0;
```

Replace player_id with the name of the column that you count the zeros in.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that is not the way to go: Assume you have 10 records, and your code takes 1s, your game grows, and you now have 10k records, so you are then waiting for 1000s (and that is with linear scaling, which is most of the time not really the case).

So a better solution is:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM games WHERE id=? AND player4=0;
```

(`player4=0` is just an example since your goal is not really clear).

Use PHP PDO to get the query to run (google php pdo examples).

And add an index on your table to identify the records faster:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_player4 ON player_table(player4);
```